# Qt Creator in Windows - How do I know which compiler is being used?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, boost

I'm running Qt Creator 3.1.1 in Windows. I have an existing Qt project and I'm trying to add the Boost library to it. I think I have the .pro file configured to correctly point to the .lib and .hpp folders. However, I still get a linking error when I compile: "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol".

From other things I've read, it looks like I need to make sure that my Boost was compiled with the same compiler I'm using to compile my Qt projects.

Here's the Boost build I installed: http://boost.teeks99.com/bin/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0-msvc-12.0-64.exe

Here's a screenshot of my Qt Creator About window:
[image]

And here's a screenshot of my Qt Creator compiler options:
[image]

How can I tell which compiler I'm using? It lists a whole bunch, but isn't very clear about which one is actually used. Also, please let me know if this could be a simple 64 vs 32 bit problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the QtCreator settings -- what you want is your [project settings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-configuring-projects.html).  In the left sidebar, click Projects.

At the top of the project pane, the selected build options for the current target appear in a little box at the top.  Hover your mouse cursor over the down arrow for the compiler and debugger details, you'll see something like this:

[image]

Comment: So my project says the compiler is "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (amd64)" Isn't that the same compiler that was used to compile my Boost build? So is the issue probably something else?

Comment: Looks like it wasn't even related to Boost. I had another library that was compiled to 32 bits and my project is 64 bits. I got the 64 bit version and it works.